# subprocess syntaxerr on try to tpcdump with python

Tags: python, macos, terminal, subprocess, tcpdump

```
#old version of setting the command
#command = 'sudo tcpdump "type mgt subtype beacon and ether src '+ bssid.get() +'" -I -c 1 -i en0 -w beacon.cap'
#command = command.split()

#improved but error still exists
command = ['sudo', 'tcpdump', '"type mgt subtype beacon and ether src ' + bssid.get() + '"', '-I', '-c', '1', '-i', 'en0', '-w', 'beacon.cap']

cmd1 = subprocess.Popen(['echo',sudo_password], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd2 = subprocess.Popen(['sudo','-S'] + command, stdin=cmd1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = cmd2.stdout.read().decode() 
print("Task2completed: " + output + "2END")
```

**Hello stackoverflow,**

I have a question about subprocess, in the previous code snippet is the problem, that I only get an syntax error:

```
tcpdump: can't parse filter expression: syntax error
```

I cannot reproduce why this error occurs, I tried typing it manually in the terminal, then it works. I also tried set $BSSID and use it in the command instead of

```
'+ bssid.get() +'
```

but that also DIDNT worked...

Im pretty sure there is also no problem with bssid.get(), because if I print the command out and then use it in the command line it works...
I thought of some kinda' error while splitting the command??
But correct me if im wrong!

Thanks very much for your help !

Comment: `command.split()` is not going to honor your quotes.  You'll get `{"sudo", "tcpdump", '"type', 'mgt', 'subtype',..]`, which is not right.  Don't use split, just set up `command` as a list to begin with.  That way, your quoted parameter can be one entry.

Comment: Also, you're setting up to do `sudo -S sudo tcpdump`.  That's not what you want, is it?

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for your effort, the last thing you said isn't supposed. thanks.
But what do you mean by 'set up command as a list' ? like should I make the command as an list by myself like that: 

command = ["tcpdump", '"', "type", "mgt", "subtype", "beacon", "and", "ether", "src", bssid.get(), '"', "-I", "-c", "1", "-i", "en0", "-w", "beacon.cap"]

?

Comment: If the filter has to be one parameter (I don't think tcpdump requires that), then I mean `command = ['sudo', 'tcpdump', '"type mgt subtype beacon and ether src " + bssid.get() + '"', '-I', '-c', '1', '-i', 'en0', ...]`.

Comment: Please reformat your code. What's with the indentation?

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for your improvement and your patience but each way I try it still comes the same syntax error... 
Do you have any other ideas ? :)

Comment: @HaiVu ohh yeah sorry. done. 
but in the real code that one is done right :))

Comment: @TimRoberts `shlex.split()` would honor the quotes. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to mix and match list-style Popen parameters and strings; just using all strings is safer and more convenient.

You can also use a `io.BytesIO()` for sending the password to `sudo`:

```
import subprocess

command = [
    "tcpdump",
    f"type mgt subtype beacon and ether src '{bssid.get()}'",
    "-I",
    "-c",
    "1",
    "-i",
    "en0",
    "-w",
    "beacon.cap",
]

cmd = subprocess.Popen(
    ["sudo", "-S"] + command,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
)
# Write the password to the subprocess's stdin.
cmd.stdin.write((f"{sudo_password}\n").encode("utf-8"))
output = cmd.stdout.read().decode()
print("Task2completed: " + output + "2END")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but if I try to use your code snippet I get an io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
error
Further more I have a question: is the f in BytesIO() and the f in the command array a typo ?

Comment: No, those are [f-strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/). Fair about the UnsupportedOperation though, let me fix that.

Comment: Please see my edit - I had forgotten you'd need a real file to pass as stdin, not an *IO.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help!
But still I get the same 
tcpdump: can't parse filter expression: syntax error
error...

Comment: Well, that's another error: you're passing something to tcpdump that isn't valid. I don't think you need `and` in there?

Comment: I finally got the error: 
the last small error where the 2  '  around the bssid, thank you so much mate! 
Shall I edit this in your code ?
thanks for your patience and kindness !
Sincerly Sheee

Answer (score 0):

I believe part of your trouble is how to split the command correctly, the way `bash` shell does it. To do that, you will need the `shlex` module:

```
import shlex
command = 'sudo -S tcpdump "type mgt subtype beacon and ether src '+ bssid.get() +'" -I -c 1 -i en0 -w beacon.cap'
command = shlex.split(command)

# Now you can call it
process = subprocess.run(
        command,
        encoding="utf-8",
        input="MyPasswordHere",
        capture_output=True,
)

# Output is in process.stdout without the need to decode.
```